# Ansible playbook throwing `playbook does not exist on the guest` when testing with Vagrant machine

Tags: ansible

When running ansible playbook in windows vagrant image, output looks like:

```
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Sorry, don't know how to check guest version of Virtualbox Guest Additions on this platform. Stopping installation.
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default: 
    default: Guest Additions Version: 5.1.12
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.2
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/aaron.west/Workspace/hss-iaas/ansible-repo/tmp
==> default: Running provisioner: ansible_local...
`playbook` does not exist on the guest: /vagrant/test/local.yml
```

The playbook can be found here: https://galaxy.ansible.com/lean_delivery/java

and the vagrant windows server 2016 image that i'm using is: `mwrock/Windows2016`

the playbook looks like:

```
- hosts: local
  gather_facts: yes
  connection: local
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  roles:
    - ../roles/java
```

Answer (score 3):

As per the [`ansible_local` documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html):

> The Ansible Local provisioner **requires that all the Ansible Playbook
>   files are available on the guest machine, at the location referred by
>   the provisioning_path option**. Usually these files are initially
>   present on the host machine (as part of your Vagrant project), and it
>   is quite easy to share them with a Vagrant Synced Folder.

To do so, add the following:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant"
```

[This configuration](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html) shares the vagrant folder from the host in the *"/vagrant"* folder on the guest, where it seems to look for the playbook as can be seen in the error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

`Running provisioner: ansible_local` – so Vagrant tries to execute playbook **inside** the guest.

You might want to refactor your playbooks to work with [ansible](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible.html) provisioner.

Answer (score 0):

Better use:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", create: true
```

Sometimes this directory is missing in the image and this leads to the same error.